# How to fix image to bottom right in gallery

Tags: html, css, image

I have a gallery working fine, but I want to add an image in bottom right of the gallery so
I would like to have:

[image]

I know this css could solve it:

```
#container_logo {
    position:fixed;
    right:0;
    bottom:0;
    margin:0;
    width:75%;
    height:75%;
    background:url(http://blog.logobee.com/free-logo1.jpg) no-repeat bottom right;
    background-size:100%;
}
```

But how to add it to the current code?

I tried adding an extra line  `background:url(http://blog.logobee.com/free-logo1.jpg)`:

```
#containingDiv {
    width:100%;
    margin:0 auto;
    padding:0px 0 0 0;
    background:url(http://blog.logobee.com/free-logo1.jpg) no-repeat bottom right;
}
```

but it is not showing in the right place...

- How could I change the container code so it has that fixed image at bottom right?

[here is result](http://jsfiddle.net/KGk9f/1/embedded/result/)

Kindly take a look at [the complete fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KGk9f/1/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at this http://jsfiddle.net/KGk9f/5/

You need to add

```
 <div id="container_logo"></div>
```

to the

```
<div id="containingDiv">
```

And make few CSS changes...

```
#containingDiv {
width:680px;    
height:470px;
position:relative;

margin:0 auto;
padding:0px 0 0 0;
}

#container_logo {
position:absolute;
z-index:500;
width:150px;
height:150px;

right:0;    
bottom:0;
margin:0;
background:url(http://blog.logobee.com/free-logo1.jpg) no-repeat bottom right;
background-size:100%;
```

}

Hope it helps...

Comment: One more question, In the case I'd like to make it responsive, I would just add that code to corresponding code? or how to accomplish, in the fiddle I have `@media screen and (min-width:1200px) {
    #containingDiv {
        width:100%;
        margin:0 auto;
        padding:0px 0 0 0;
    }` so I would just add your code for each case, wouldn't I

Comment: yes, you would need to add my CSS changes to those as well, just make sure to adjust them as needed...

Answer (score 1):

Try setting the width of the `div` containing the logo to the width of the `div` containing the picture (make sure this is a non-changing number such as percents). If the height and width are the same as the larger picture. Setting `bottom: 0px; right: 0px;` for the logo should make it appear in the bottom right of the picture. If you are using `margin` and `padding` to adjust where the main picture is, make sure it is included for the logo picture so they sit in the same spot no matter what size window it is being viewed in.